# form verification before submitting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have following form

```
<form id="myForm" action="/Problems/Post"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="problemSubject" name="problemSubject" />
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile"/>
<textarea rows="" cols="" class="form-textarea" id="problemDescription" name="problemDescription"></textarea>
</form>
```

I have to submit form to controller method(which i have done), but it should be first validated  i.e. it should not contain empty fields. What i want is that "a message should appear telling that field is blank". How this can be done. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the samples. (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

Essentially you can validate on client side and on server side, which you should do both.

It is very easy to do validation in asp.net mvc3. Look at some tutorials like above.

Or this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249452/ASP-NET-MVC3-Validation-Basic

Answer (score 0):

u can use server side validation controls...
plz hv a look [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

or use the jquery gven below--->

```
function callOnload(){

    if($('#problemSubject').val() == '')
    alert('fill the values');

    if($('#uploadFile').val() == '')
    alert('fill the values');
}
```